# spyOn and createSpyObj in the same spec jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, spyon

I'm using Jasmine to test this

```
class X{
   test(obj){
    return obj.someFunction()+100
  }
}
```

so my spec is

```
it("test if someFunction is called and return value calculated correctly",()=>{
  let x = new X()

   let mockObj= jasmine.createSpyObj(["someFunction"])
      mockObj.someFunction.and.callFake(()=> 2000)

  let returnValue= x.test(mockObj)

   expect (mockObj.someFunction).toHaveBeenCalled()
   expect (returnValue).toBe(2000+100)
})
```

And this is ok
Now I want to check if **the parameter of test() is an object** as data type
so I want to do this

```
   spyOn(x,"test")
   let mockObj= jasmine.createSpyObj(["someFunction"])
   x.test(mockObj)
   expect(x.test.calls.allArgs()[0][0]).toBeInstanceOf(Object)
```

And this is ok in another it()

**But** why can't we do both in the same it() block?
Is it not valid to use spyOn() and createSpyObj() in the same it() block?

If I did so the it() will **fail**! and **this is the error** I'm getting

```
Expected spy unknown.someFunction to have been called
Expected undefined to be 2100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we do `spyOn`, we are attaching a spy on the method and letting go of its implementation details. So after we spy on `test` method, we can see how many times it was called, how it was called, etc. but we lose it's implementation details (what's inside of the method).

To get the best of both worlds (still have implementation details and know if it was called, how it was called, etc.), we need to use `.and.callThrough();`.

Change the first line here like so:

```
// add .and.callThrough() here.
spyOn(x,"test").and.callThrough();
let mockObj= jasmine.createSpyObj(["someFunction"])
x.test(mockObj)
expect(x.test.calls.allArgs()[0][0]).toBeInstanceOf(Object)
```

That way, the `test` method will be spied upon and the actual method will be called.

**Edit**
You can use `callFake` as well but you have to provide a function implementation.

```
spyOn(x,"test").and.callFake((arg) => {
  if (arg) {
    return 300;
  }
  return 400;
});
```

You can do something based on the argument. In this case, if it exists, it will return 300 and if it doesn't, it will return 400;

Comment: Thanks that works. but what about `callFake()` does it provide a mock implementation and call it, or do I still need to use `callThrough()`?

Comment: Check out my edit on how to use `callFake`. It should be used when we need a mock function implementation.